# I'm having trouble loading my android physical phone, it keeps says loading device for hours and nothing happens

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, adb, android-debug

[this the screenshot of my Android Studio, I'm trying to learn flutter but I'm having issues while setting my physical device to it, android studio says loading device for hours and nothing happens, and even I'm failing to initialize ABD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMxWh.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on the top side of your screenshot, the android studio doesn't recognize your physical android device. Make sure that your phone is connected properly and USB debugging is turned on. also you can install ADB directly if it was not included in the Android SDK.

Comment: but the problem is that it works sometime, I will try installing ADB, this should work

Comment: It did not work, I tried even re installing but the issue remain same. I even tried installing ADB yet it didn't work.

Comment: It's hard to debug your problem with just a screenshot. Provide me with stacktrace of the problem.